# Submit on JSP gives a blank page and doesn't load it

Tags: java, jsp, web

When I submit the form - it redirects me to the link I want, but the page is blank.

Here is the code of form in JSP:

```
<form class="inscription-form" method="post" action="apropos">
        <hr style="color: blue">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" name="nom" id="nom" class="form-control" 
             placeholder="pseudo">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >inscriprion</button>
    </form>
```

**When the link is the same page it gives me 404 error !**

Here is the Java code:

```
public class inscription extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public inscription() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }


    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse 
    response) throws ServletException, IOException {

         request.setAttribute("utilisateur",utilisateur);
         this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/WEB- 
         INF/inscription.jsp").forward(request, response);

    }


    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse 
    response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        utilisateur = new Utilisateur();
        utilisateur.setNom(request.getParameter("nom"));
        request.setAttribute("utilisateur",utilisateur);
        this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/inscription.jsp")
                                .forward(request, response);

    }

}
```

thank you for help

Comment: please post the url mapping for `inscription`

Comment: <servlet>
    <servlet-name>inscription</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.octest.servlets.inscription</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>inscription</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/inscription</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

Comment: did you mean `action="inscription"` in the form?

Comment: You need to pass url-pattern in form action instead of servlet-name. action="inscription" instead of action="apropos".

Comment: action="http://www.salhi.com/"> i did it but still doesn't work

Comment: http://www.salhi.com is like localhost/

Comment: apropos is another jsp file in the same folder i tried them all links like youtube or others work fine but jsp files don't load

Comment: "/WEB-INF/inscription.jsp" does not look right. Why JSPs are in WEB-INF folder. Move them outside and you should be able to access it.